# TCPDF go to page

Tags: php, tcpdf

Is their a way that I can go back to a previous page after calling addPage more than once because when I call write it adds it to the current page where I need it to write on the first page. I have been through its documentation and cannot seem to find anything?

By the way I am creating my pdf in php

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was solved using the following code,

```
$numPages = $fpdi2->getNumPages();

for($int=1;$int < $numPages + 1; $int++){
    $fpdi2->setPage($int );
    // do your code here with that page
}
```

Comment: but what about going to a page and then ADDING a new page from there? seems that this is not working. for me its overwriting the next page.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your program logic.